# Transform Service Fabric Config Or Any XML file with namespace on root element using MSBuild

Tags: xml, msbuild, transform, azure-service-fabric

I am trying to transform config.xml file in a service fabric app. The problem i am facing is that the root element of source xml has namespaces with has to be retained after transformation. the TransformXml task in msbuild only works if root element of source xml has no namespaces.

**SOURCE XML**

```
<Application xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
             Name="SomeName" 
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2011/01/fabric">
  <Parameters>
    <Parameter Name="Key" Value="Default" />
    </Parameters>
</Application>
```

**TRANSFORM FILE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Application Name="ApplicationName"              
             xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform"   
             xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(Name)">
  <Parameters>
    <Parameter Name="Key" Value="TransformedValue" xdt:Locator="Match(Name)" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(Value)"/>    
  </Parameters>
</Application>
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
<Application xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
             Name="ApplicationName" 
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2011/01/fabric">
  <Parameters>
    <Parameter Name="Key" Value="TransformedValue" />
    </Parameters>
</Application>
```

When i run this transform by using TransformXml task. i get this as warning and i don't get expected output.

```
no element in the source document matches /Application
```

I hope someone has done this before. Any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: Why not use token replace task?

Comment: @Mardoxx what is 'token replace task'? I am using msbuild.exe to build the project. you might be talking about visual studio online build server. I specifically need it to build/transform on developer machine too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use parameter files in Service Fabric to override config settings at deployment time: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-manage-multiple-environment-app-configuration

Comment: I understand that is how its done by default but the problem i am trying to solve is that even though i can add xml file for each environment, i still need to make sure if i add new parameter to manifest file, then i add that parameter to all other files (fst, uat, prod etc.) that's why i want to create all the other files by transforming the values i need to change. Secondly i find this problem to be generic for any config file which has namespace in the root element.

Comment: I would recommend you change the title of the question to that and tag it with msbuild.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is super old, but just in case anyone else runs into the same problem.

We ran into the same issue because we are running pipelines in Azure DevOps and needed to move our non-sensitive parameters moved out the variable groups and into a file that can be checked into source control instead. XML transformations, while annoying support this and since Service Fabric uses the Cloud.xml parameter file we needed to go this route.

The answer was to remove the `xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2011/01/fabric"` from the `Application` tag within the Cloud.xml.

Doing this allowed the XML transform task to correctly apply the Cloud.[Environment].xml transformations.

There is apparently some issue with the xml namespaces. The only reason we found this solve, was due finding two other items with the same fix, different namespace, but removing the xmlns tag solved it.
Sources:

- [Care of Mark Biek](https://mark.biek.org/blog/2014/03/a-frustrating-webconfig-transformation-error/)
- [Reported on GitHub](https://github.com/CameronWills/FatAntelope/issues/6)

Also as @Gurpreet mentioned, this allows us to use the same approach for local development to get the transforms done in Visual Studio with the aid of Slow Cheetah.